# Let $W_{1},W_{2}$ be sub-spaces of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$, find a subspace $W_{3}$ s.t $W_3\subset W_{2}$ and $W_{1}\oplus W_{3}=W_{1}+W_{2}$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $W_{1},W_{2}$ be  linear sub-spaces of $\mathbb{R}^{4}$.

$W_{1}=\text{sp}\{(1,2,3,4),(3,4,5,6),(7,8,9,10)\}$

$W_{2}=\text{sp }\{(x,y,z,w)| \ x+y=0\}$

> Find a linear subspace of  $ \  \mathbb{R}^{4} \  ; W_{3}$ , such that: $W_{3}\subset W_{2} \  \text {*and*} \  W_{1}\oplus W_{3}=W_{1}+W_{2}$

My attempt:

I applied Gaussian elimination on the vectors of $W_1$, such that:

$$W_{1}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right)=a\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
-2\\
-1
\end{array}\right)+b\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
-2\\
-1
\end{array}\right)|a,b\in\mathbb{R}\right\} $$

At that point I got stuck. I'm not sure how to continue.

Comment: Your Gaussian elimination seems wrong. How can $(1,2,3,4)$ belong to $W_{1}$ if  your Gaussian elimination is correct ?

Comment: checked it in wolfam alpha, it's correct

Comment: It is « obviously » as you say, not correct. Give me your $a$ and your $b$ such as $(1,2,3,4)$ belongs to your $W_{1}$.

Comment: @Jneven Pjonin is right there is some problem in the basis you have found for $W_1$. Check again it is trivial also by inspection that (1,1,1,1) and (0,1,2,3) work fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

We should write as a span (check again you derivation by RREF)

$$W_{1}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right)=s\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\
1\\
1
\end{array}\right)+t\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
1\\
2\\
3
\end{array}\right)\right\}$$

and we can  also easily find that

$$W_{2}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right)=r\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)+s\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)+t\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\}$$

then check by RREF on the $5$ basis vectors that $W_{1}+W_{2}$ has dimension $4$ and finally select 2 basis vectors for $W_3$ from the basis vectors of $W_2$ such that  $W_{1}\oplus W_{3}=\mathbb{R^4}$.

Answer (score 1):

(I won't change the notation although it's not 100% correct)

Hint: Rewrite the basis of $W_1$ as
$$W_{1}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right)=a\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
0\\
-2\\
-1
\end{array}\right)+b\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)\right\} $$

A basis of $W_2$ is
$$W_{2}=\left\{ \left(\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z\\
w
\end{array}\right)=a\left(\begin{array}{c}
1\\
-1\\
0\\
0
\end{array}\right)+b\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
1\\
0
\end{array}\right)+c\left(\begin{array}{c}
0\\
0\\
0\\
1
\end{array}\right)\right\} $$

can you take it from here?

Comment: to see that I got this right (this what I was thinking needed to be done) - I looked for a vector $x$ that applies $x \in W_1 \cap W_2$, 
and then tried to transform this expression into a matrix. but my matrix was in size of  $4 \times 5$ which got me completely confused.

Answer (score 0):

Hint : what is the dimension of $W_{1}$ ? As a consequence, what should be the dim of $W_{3}$ ? What must verify a vector in $W_{3}$?

Comment: obviously dim $W_1 =2$ and dim $W_1 \leq 3 $

Comment: Be more modest. Seems not that obvious since you are giving a wrong answer.